# Pandas add new column as "agregation" of different columns but counting them as 1 in case value > 0

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get the column "N_CLAIMS" as an aggregation of "MONTHS_N_INCIDENT" but if it's > 0 count as 1

[image]

what should be the optimal way for many columns and rows instead to iterate over the dataframe

Comment: What effort have you put into solving this problem? Please add some code to your post.

Comment: Hi @Vishnudev, I could do it by iterating over the df, but I want the cleanest and optimal way. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess aggregation is sum? But in anycase you can do your aggregation across the columns and check if > 0 and cast it to int as you want 0 and 1 not True and False. So something like

```py
columns = ["col1", ...] # if you only need some columns
df["newcolumn"] = (df[colums] > 0).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Comment: not really this.. my objective is to create the column "N_CLAIMS". It should be an aggregation of the other values but counting them as an 1 or 0 only. Did I explained myself?

Comment: Ok, so I didn't understand it. I have updated my answer. Is that what you mean? If not I will delete it. Of course you can just rename newcolumn to N_CLAIMS

Comment: You misspelled "columns" the second time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `df[columns].gt(0).sum(axis=1)`.